# bootstrap accordion trigger open/close from within

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to close a bootstrap panel from clicking a button nested inside. I know its possible, just cant reach the scope.I have calling the collapse class, I have tried showing and hiding it--any ideas?

```js
$( "#button1" ).click(function() {
//close accordion 1 and open accordon 3
  $("#collapseTwo").collapse();
  $("#collapseThree").CollapseIn();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div class="bs-example">
    <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">1. What is HTML?</a>
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <p>HTML stands for HyperText Markup Language. HTML is the main markup language for describing the structure of Web pages. <a id="button1">Learn more.</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo">2. What is Bootstrap?</a>
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <p>Bootstrap is a powerful front-end framework for faster and easier web development. It is a collection of CSS and HTML conventions. <a href="http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/twitter-bootstrap-tutorial/" target="_blank">Learn more.</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree">3. What is CSS?</a>
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <p>CSS stands for Cascading Style Sheet. CSS allows you to specify various style properties for a given HTML element such as colors, backgrounds, fonts etc. <a href="http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/css-tutorial/" target="_blank">Learn more.</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this and commenting out your javascript:

```
    <a id="button1" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne">Learn more.</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
$( "#button1" ).click(function() {
  //close accordion 1 and open accordion 3
  $("#collapseOne, #collapseThree").collapse('toggle');
});
```

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/beginnerCF/7cem6wL6/).

**OR**

```
<a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree" id="button1">Learn more.</a>
```

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/beginnerCF/7cem6wL6/1/).

Answer (score 0):

I went further into the collapse comparing to the preview answers and found out:
here are some more methods inside the collapse event provided in jQuery
***toggle***, ***show***, ***hide***, ***setTransitioning*** and ***dispose***. But i have no idea what is it the two last.

[image]

User them as the second parameter in the event `` $(`#id`).collapse('show') ``.

*More over i solved much more complex task*:
I had siblign components which are separated and dont know about each other (two form sets and submit button, see the pic).

[image]

I put a custom event trigger in the submit button

```
    onSubmitHandler = (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      $(window).trigger(EVENT_SET_EXPEND_BEFORE_SUBMIT)
...
```

and added custom event listener to set components to expand them when the button is clicked (to improve user experience)

```
function (props) {
  function onExpandSet(e) {
    $(`#id`).collapse('show')
  }
  $(window).on(EVENT_SET_EXPEND_BEFORE_SUBMIT, onExpandSet);
}
```